# Avoid executing event's default action. `event.cancelable` vs `event.preventDefault`?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

When I don't want to execute the default action that is associated with the event, I use

```
function listener(e){
    if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    /* Other code */
}
```

But [I have just learnt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.cancelable) that events have the boolean `cancelable`. Then, should I use this code instead?

```
function listener(e){
    if(e.cancelable) e.preventDefault();
    /* Other code */
}
```

I wonder:

- If `event.preventDefault` is `true`, does it really mean that the event is cancelable? Maybe if it isn't cancelable, that attribute is defined (and `true`), but it isn't a function; or it's a function but if I call it it throws an error.
- Does all browsers (IE, I'm looking at you) support `event.cancelable`? Is there a browser which has the method `event.preventDefault` but doesn't have `event.cancelable`; or has the method `event.cancelable` but doesn't have `event.preventDefault`; or that `event.cancelable` doesn't always imply that `event.preventDefault` is defined and it's a function and it doesn't throw errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
if (e.preventDefault)
```

merely means that the event object has a property called "preventDefault".  It's a browser feature test, because old versions of IE didn't have that. Instead, in IE you set the property "returnValue" on the event object to `false`.

Thus, the reason you test for "preventDefault" is to see whether that function is available; if the property is null, you obviously can't make the function call.  So when you want to prevent the default action, your code should look like this:

```
if (e.preventDefault)
  e.preventDefault();
else
  e.returnValue = false;
```

If the "cancelable" flag is false, then that means you *cannot* prevent default behavior. The "preventDefault" function is still there (if it normally would be), but calls to it are ignored for non-cancelable events. There's no need to check the flag at all, really; it's a static characteristic of the particular type of event, usually.

Comment: He can't but Jon Skeet can!

Comment: @Oriol, you better delete the question before a mod see the comment and ban you for good!

Comment: @Oriol Mr. Skeet is a Stackoverflow participant with enough reputation points to *literally* transcend time and space.

Comment: @Pointy I'm not sure if I understand you with "*Preventing the default action of an event is something you do because you want to, not because the browser tells you to*". If I want the browser to do something but the browser can't do that, I should ask it first, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 0):

First you can check if the event is [cancelable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelable). Know that not all events are cancelable, for example the `change` event.

After that you check if the event has been [defaultPrevented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented).

```js
if (!event.cancelable || !event.defaultPrevented) {
  // execute the event logic, because the previous event didn't prevented it
}
```

The `cancelable` check is optional, but I use it to remind myself that not all events are cancelable.